# Linux threads for dummies. Can some one explain the difference between multi-thread libraries in linux?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading

New to linux and c++.
I wante to create an application that only needs to run on linux (ubuntuz) and i need to use basic read-write locks.

I saw that there are a few libraries that give "concurrency capabilities".
e.g. to use mutexes, there are at least 3 options:

1. pthread_mutex_lock (pthread.h)
2. boost::mutex
3. std::mutex (mutex)

could someone explain the differences between the various approaches?

Comment: You can also use std::mutex, which is similar to boost's.

Comment: Don't forget that the "new" C++11 standard also have threading capabilites, see e.g. [`std::mutex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex).

Comment: look on option 3 i included it there . what do you mean by similar? syntax or implementation?

Comment: By syntax..if you mean design..yes.Btw is in <mutex> not <mutex.h>.

Comment: std::mutex is (conceptually) derived from boost::mutex [actually a whole lot of the new libraries are adapted from boost with (minor) changes]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- pthreads is a C-API and is available on all posix conformant systems (`pthreads` stands for `Posix THREADS`).
- boost::mutex is a C++-only API that depends on the "boost"-library (you cannot use it in C-code; you add a dependency on "boost")
- lots of features from boost will eventually end up in the C++ standard library, e.g. threading; with C++11 you have std::mutex, but you will need a compiler recent enough to support that recent addition. e.g. if you want your application to be backportable to older distributions you might want to avoid it.

Answer (score 3):

`std::mutex` is part of the standard library. Every C++ compiler/library vendor is free to implement it in any way they like. A library implementation for Posix will more likely than not just use pthreads under the hood, while for instance a Windows library would use the Windows API primitives.

If you can, use `std::mutex`, but if you don't have C++11 support yet, write your own SBRM classes that wrap the pthread mutex and locking primitives, or use Boost if that's feasible (e.g. if your project already uses Boost anyway). It'll all come down to the same thing anyway.

Comment: can you please explain why there are lot of options?

Comment: That's like explaining why there are lots of kinds of breakfast cereals, when all they do is invariably provide a sugar rush... :-) Pthreads is a platform-specific, fundamental, lower-level C library. `std::mutex` is part of the C++ standard. It's comparing apples and bears. And as I said, one may well be implemented in terms of the other.

Comment: :) some time options means disadvantage and advantages :)

Comment: @user1495181: No, not at all. As I said (seriously), they're different domains, and most likely, the C++ standard library facility (`std::mutex`) will be **implemented in terms of** the pthreads primitive on a Posix platform. So you should use the standard library whenever possible, but the standard library wouldn't exist on your platform without the platform specific primitive facilities.